# Remove and extract text in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm wanting to do the following in JavaScript as efficiently as possible:

1. Remove `<ul></ul>` tags from a string and everything in between.
2. For what remains, every string that is encased within `<li>` and `</li>` I want dumped in an array, without any newline characters lurking at the end.

I'm thinking regexes are the answer but I've never used them before. Guess I could figure out a way but eventually it would probably not be the most efficient.

Comment: You can be pretty sure that regexes are not the answer. Just search for "regex HTML" here on SO. [Then read this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686936/javascript-remove-all-content-between-some-tags).

Comment: while you *can* use RegEx, if your HTML is well formed xml (or XHTML) , you might want to try XSL. That is designed for transforming XML-like data.

Comment: its an oldy but some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you do have to be careful parsing HTML with regexes.  If the HTML is controlled and does not have nested `ul` or `li` tags in it and doesn't have embedded strings that contain valid HTML tags or < or > chars (e.g. the HTML is coming from a known source in a known format, it can work fine).  Here's one way to do what I think you were asking for:

```
function parseList(str) {
    var output = [], matches;
    var re = /<\s*li[^>]*>(.*?)<\/li>/gi;
    // remove newlines
    str = str.replace(/\n|\r/igm, "");
    // get text between ul tags
    matches = str.match(/<\s*ul[^>]*>(.*?)<\/ul\s*>/);
    if (matches) {
        str = matches[1];
        // get text between each li tag
        while (matches = re.exec(str)) {
            output.push(matches[1]);
        }
    }
    return(output);
}
```

It is more foolproof to use an actual HTML parser that understands the finer points of the format (like nested tags, tag values in embedded strings, etc...), but if you have none of that, a simpler parser like this can be used.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/c9ZLT/